# What is the best way to add an Item x of total to each item while sorting an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given an array of items representing individual line items within orders:

```
var_export([[
        'order_id' => 1,
        'driver_id' => 100,
        'product_id' => 2
      ],
      [ 
        'order_id' => 1,
        'driver_id' => 100,
        'product_id' => 1
      ],
      [
        'order_id' => 2,
        'driver_id' => 50,
        'product_id' => 1
      ]
]);
```

that has to be sorted by driver_id, then product_id. Is it possible to add an additional field to each item during the sort such that at the end I have something like:

```
var_export([[
        'order_id' => 2,
        'driver_id' => 50,
        'product_id' => 1,
        'sequence' => '1 of 1'
      ],
      [ 
        'order_id' => 1,
        'driver_id' => 100,
        'product_id' => 1,
        'sequence' => '1 of 2' //if easier, this could be 2 of 2 and the one below 1 of 2 as long as they are ordered this way in the array
      ],
      [
        'order_id' => 1,
        'driver_id' => 100,
        'product_id' => 2,
        'sequence' => '2 of 2'
      ]
]);
```

Where `sequence` shows an iterative count of the item within the order (order_id 1 has two items in total so each should have a sequence x of 2, but it is not important which item within the order is marked 1 of and which is marked 2 of).

If it's not possible to do this while sorting, what is the best way to add this field after?

Comment: for the future, please, use `var_export` for showing the source data. that way it can be copy paste.

Comment: @sevavietl I've updated to use var_export and have changed the data to show sort ordering more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
// Get array of all order ids.
$orderIds = array_column($array, 'order_id');
// Sort $array by order ids.
array_multisort(
    array_column($array, 'driver_id'),
    array_column($array, 'product_id'),
    $orderIds,
    $array
);
// Count order ids occurances.
$orderIdsCounts = array_count_values($orderIds);

$counter = 0;
$array = array_map(function ($orderId, $item) use (&$counter, $orderIdsCounts) {
    $counter += 1;

    $item['sequence'] = "$counter of {$orderIdsCounts[$orderId]}";

    // Reset the counter if order id total is reached.
    $counter = $counter === $orderIdsCounts[$orderId] ? 0 : $counter;

    return $item; 
}, $orderIds, $array);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e98200257ef1445727b29a01aa3561c9d869bd99).

Comment: That gets and adds the sequence field but doesn't reorder the original array. I was asking if it were possible to do both at the same time. With the original array ordered by `driver_id`, then `product_id`. So can that map function be mixed into a `usort` or is it a case of having to do two separate iterations to achieve my desired result?

Comment: @RobinSouthgate, maybe you can do all at once, but this really complicates the logic. So I would pass two more arguments to `array_multisort`. See the updated answer.